# How to Preventing Empty Data from Inserting into database in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How to Preventing Empty Data from Inserting into database in laravel?

In some cases,datas are saved into the database as empty record.

[image]

Comment: validate before inserting data

Comment: I have added validation rules before insertion,but in some rare cases record saved as empty.Is there any options like Fillable to avoid empty insertion of the entire record?

Comment: Make sure the column cannot be null in the migration

Comment: Can you post your `Controller` and `blade` code?

Comment: If, with validation rules, you get empty input, the validation rules are not correct. You can make fields not nullable in the db too, but that will throw an error.

Comment: Check it out https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel validation rule "filled"

> The field under validation must not be empty when it is present.

Sample:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'filled',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        ....
    }

    ....
}
```

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-filled